# does a 2004 ford focus sedan hood fit on the hatchback model?

Tags: ford, focus, hood

hey i am trying to find a replacement hood for my 2004 ford focus hatchback, and from what i can tell every focus model from 2000 to 2004 will fit, but i dont want to drive 2 hours to pick up a used hood and find out it wont fit.

if you know, that would be helpful, or if you could direct me to the correct website to find something like that out, that would be helpful as well. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The fronts of those cars are all the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the hood from a savage yard and they say it will fit it's a pretty safe bet. They use an interchange guide,  Holander for example that gives them all of that information.  You can also check car-part.com I believe they will give you the interchange information and you might even find a better price.